# Keystrokes triggered by hotstring sent in wrong order in AutoHotkey v2

Tags: windows, automation, autohotkey

I wrote a hotstring to insert German doublequotes into text inputs.

They look like this:

```
„“
```

This is my hotstring waiting for input `~+`:

```autohotkey
:*  :~+:: {
  Send "„{Left}“"
}
```

I want it to output `„“` and set my caret back since I want to write quoted text between the doublequotes, not after them.

It actually outputs `“„` instead and I have no idea why.

My temporary fix is intentionally swapping the characters in the `Send` function call:

```autohotkey
:*  :~+:: {
  Send "“{Left}„" ; Need the quote characters in reverse order for some reason
}
```

It works for me this way, but what would be the real fix to this?
Using AutoHotkey v2 2.0-a129.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quite simply sending the wrong thing, haha. Think about it.
`„{Left}“`
First you're sending `„`
Then you're sending `{left}`, so your caret ends up here `|„`
Then you're sending `“`, so you're typing this quote in front of the first one.

What you actually want to do is this
`„“{Left}`

---

Misc improvements:
I don't know why you put two spaces into the options part, but I'm pretty sure they're not doing anything? Can just remove them.
And you also don't need the send command for anything, the hotstring syntax works just like this
`:*:~+::„“{Left}`

Comment: Thank you very much. I feel so dumb right now. :D

Comment: Also thanks for the simplified syntax. The whitespaces are there to keep alignment with other hotstrings in the same AHK file that use more hotstring options than the doublequotes one. But I didn't know I can send {Left} without actually using the Send function, so this definitely helps me too.